# Dynamic `v-model` for computed properties - based on route param

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router, v-model

I am building a component that can be used to set various vuex properties, depending on the name passed in the route. Here is the naive gist of it:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="this[$route.params.name]"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    foo: {
      get(){ return this.$store.state.foo; },
      set(value){ this.$store.commit('updateValue', {name:'foo', value}); }
    },
    bar: {
      get(){ return this.$store.state.bar; },
      set(value){ this.$store.commit('updateValue', {name:'bar', value}); }
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Note that I pass `this[$route.params.name]` to the `v-model`, to make it dynamic. This works for setting (component loads fine), but when trying to set a value, I get this error:

`Cannot set reactive property on undefined, null, or primitive value: null`

I assume this is because `this` inside `v-model` becomes undefined (?)

How can I make this work?

## UPDATE

I would also be curious to know why this does not work (compilation error):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="getComputed()"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    foo: {
      get(){ return this.$store.state.foo; },
      set(value){ this.$store.commit('updateValue', {name:'foo', value}); }
    },
    bar: {
      get(){ return this.$store.state.bar; },
      set(value){ this.$store.commit('updateValue', {name:'bar', value}); }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getComputed(){
      return this[this.$route.params.name]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah everything inside your `<template>` is in the `this` scope, so `this` is undefined.

`v-model` is just a syntactic sugar for `:value` and `@input`, so you can handle this with a custom event and a computed property for `:value`.

You can also use a computed property with a getter and setter; Something like

```
computed: {
  model: {
    get: function () {
      return this.$store.state[this.$route.params.name]
    },
    set: function (value) {
      this.$store.commit('updateValue', { name: this.$route.params.name, value})
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit**
If you have more logic to do in your setter, i'd separate it like so, keep the getter simple, and stick to one computed property;

```
computed: {
  model: {
    get: function () {
      return this.$store.state[this.$route.params.name]
    },
    set: function (value) {
      switch(this.$route.params.name) {
        case 'foo':
          return this.foo(value)
        default:
          return this.bar(value)
      }
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  foo(val) {
    this.$store.commit(...)
  },
  bar(val) {
    this.$store.commit(...)
  }
}
```

Comment: I see how the first suggestion would work, but that would complicate code a lot. Regarding the second solution: I do some different checks in the setters, so a generic setter is not really an option. Nothing closer to my naive example possible you think?

Comment: I was thinking of some intermediate `method` that returns the correct computed property, based on the current route param. Does not seem to work that way though.

Comment: Hm, not that i know of. I would divide the setter if you have some more complicated code, split it up that way. Let me update my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't look too bad. I updated the question with an alternative that uses an intermediate method. That gives a compilation error. You know why?

Comment: That's because v-model requires a variable that can be set as well as get; a method is always a getter (callable that returns a value/null) but cannot be written to. A computed property w. setter / getter can be written to.

Comment: Ah yes, I figured as much but couldn't put it to words. Thanks for the `switch` idea, I think it best conveys the generic intention of the code.